# How can I make multiple parameters in an anonymous function implicit?

Tags: scala

If we have a method that accepts an anonymous function `A => B` as a parameter, we can make `A` implicit in our invocation.

```
def impl(a: Int)(f: Int => Int): Int = f(a)

impl(a) { implicit z =>
    ...
}
```

But can we do this with anonymous functions that have multiple parameters?

```
def impl(a: Int, b: Int)(f: (Int, Int) => Int): Int = f(a, b)
```

Ideally, this would work something like:

```
impl(1, 2) { implicit (a, b) => // wrong
    ...
}
```

Or

```
impl(1, 2) { (implicit a, implicit b) => // also wrong
    ...
}
```

I can work around this using `A => B => C`, instead:

```
def impl(a: Int, b: Int)(f: Int => Int => Int): Int = f(a)(b)

impl(1, 2) { implicit a => implicit b =>
    ...
}
```

But is there a way to do this without currying the functions?

It should be obvious, but `Int` is just a dummy placeholder here.

Comment: From what I can see here https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1492 , this is discussed only for anonymous functions with a single parameter. Not sure if it is a limitation.

Comment: On a side note, Intellij says this: `It is not allowed to introduce implicit parameter because of incorrect usage count of parameter`

Comment: Yeah, based on that issue, it seems like it's just not possible.

Comment: Moreover in http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#anonymous-functions It just says `A named parameter of an anonymous function may be optionally preceded by an implicit modifier. In that case the parameter is labeled implicit` But it doesn't say anything on the restriction. Its a mystery.

Comment: I guess it could potentially lead to ambiguous implicits if the parameter types are the same (as in my example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  From section [6.23 Anonymous Functions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#anonymous-functions) of the spec, the anonymous function syntax is:

```
Expr            ::=  (Bindings | ['implicit'] id | '_') '=>' Expr
ResultExpr      ::=  (Bindings | (['implicit'] id | '_') ':' CompoundType) '=>' Block
Bindings        ::=  '(' Binding {',' Binding} ')'
Binding         ::=  (id | '_') [':' Type]
```

As you can see, the `implicit` case is special cased to only have 1 identifier, while the repetitive case `Bindings` (which uses the repetition syntax `{...}` of [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)) precludes use of `implicit`.

The only added details for `implicit` in this section are:

> A named parameter of an anonymous function may be optionally preceded by an implicit modifier. In that case the parameter is labeled implicit; however the parameter section itself does not count as an implicit parameter section in the sense defined [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicit-parameters-and-views.html#implicit-parameters). Hence, arguments to anonymous functions always have to be given explicitly.

I think that this text should also clarify that this only works for a single parameter (e.g. "A named parameter of an anonymous function that has exactly 1 parameter...")

Of course, the simplest workaround is to eschew the syntactic sugar and rebind the anonymous function parameters to new implicit variables:

```
impl(a) { (b, c) =>
    implicit val (impB, imbC) = (b, c)
    ...
}
```